# Pop up window to enter user input from windows service when localhost(localhost://1110/PostData) REST calls(POSTMAN, ARC)

Tags: windows, winforms, rest, windows-services, visual-c++-2010

I have a requirement, when localhost call like [localhost://1110/PostData] to windows service., User Input box has to popup from windows service and need to take the input from there. Currently I have created the windows service and it takes the input(URL) from the specific application and giving the proper output.

But I should be able to Pop up window to enter user input from any of the REST POST tools by calling the locahost URL.

Comment: Have you considered creating a small app that would show the dialog and return the user input on the stdout pipe?

Comment: @Michael, yes. Any immediate solution would be much helpful.

Comment: Check out this MS example: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682499(v=vs.85).aspx.  The easiest way is to use boost.process, if you use boost 1.63+

Comment: Sorry, if it not that immediate,but MS didn't make it very easy.  In any case I'd suggest you consider using boost for anything c++.